# Boost Microseconds

Tags: c++, boost, time

I am doing the follows

```
using namespace boost::posix_time;
ptime epoch = time_from_string("1970-01-01 00:00:00.000");
ptime other = time_from_string("2011-08-09 17:27:00.000.000");
time_duration const diff = other - epoch;
long long ms = diff.total_microseconds();
cout<<"diff is"<<ms<<endl;
```

The echo I get is 
    diff is 1312910820000000

Then when I change the ptime other to

```
ptime other = time_from_string("2011-08-09 17:27:00.000.100");
```

And I get the same echo, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format is incorrect, you had too many `.` separators: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac2bc272f88bc191)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>

int main() 
{
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    ptime epoch = from_time_t(0);
    ptime other = time_from_string("2011-08-09 17:27:00.000000");
    std::cout << "diff is " << (other - epoch).total_microseconds() << std::endl;

    other = time_from_string("2011-08-09 17:27:00.00001");
    std::cout << "diff is " << (other - epoch).total_microseconds() << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
diff is 1312910820000000
diff is 1312910820000010
```